# Is there any way to rotate the image in a <BackgroundImage> element [React Native]

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to rotate the image in my `<BackgroundImage>` element by 45 degrees.
I do not have the ability to change the source image.
I cannot use the regular `<Image>` property.

I've consulted the docs and done a few searches and was unable to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use a css class on the element.

```
import React from "react";
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const image = { uri: "https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png" };

const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ImageBackground source={image} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Inside</Text>
    </ImageBackground>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    transform: [{ rotate: '45deg' }]
  },
  text: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 42,
    lineHeight: 84,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#000000c0"
  }
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, I think it will helpful

```
   <ImageBackground source={require("../Assets/icon.png")} style={{height:100,width:100,transform: [{ rotate: "180deg" }],}}>
      <View style={{transform: [{ rotate: "180deg" }]}}>
         <Text>fgf</Text>
      </View>
   </ImageBackground>
```

I hope it will fixed your query.

Comment: This is actually a clever way of doing it! I'd use this but I ended up just using `position: absolute` and `overflow: hidden` to achieve the same background image affect